How to get ngx-toastr to close in angular 17.3.8 (standalone) with SSR
ngx-toastr Will not close in angular 17.3.8 (standalone) with SSR
Steps to reproduce:
Create Application with Angular CLI version 17.3.8
npx @angular/cli@17.3.8 new ng-toaster
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? Sass (SCSS)     [ https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss]
? Do you want to enable Server-Side Rendering (SSR) and Static Site Generation (SSG/Prerendering)? Yes
√ Packages installed successfully.

Install ngx-toastr
npm install ngx-toastr --save

Installs ("ngx-toastr": "^19.0.0",)
Update src\app\app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { provideToastr } from 'ngx-toastr';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideToastr({
      timeOut: 2000,
      progressBar: true,
      progressAnimation: 'decreasing',
      closeButton: true
    })
  ]
};

Update src\styles.scss
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr';

Update src\app\app.component.ts
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-toaster';
  private readonly _toasterService = inject(ToastrService);

  constructor() {
    this._toasterService.success('Close already!');
  }

  clear(){
    console.log(`Clear`);
    this._toasterService.clear();
  }
}

Update src\app\app.component.html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Toaster please close</p>
<button type="button" (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
<router-outlet />

Run
npm run start


Visit  http://localhost:4200/
The toast appears the progress bar is decreasing but it will not go away
Clicking the clear button logs the message in the console but the toast will not go away

I tried setting the timeOut both on the provideToastr() but also in the AppComponent (this._toasterService.success) but it will not work. Clearing messages will also not work with this._toasterService.clear();

The toaster is also getting opened in SSR, which is causing this weird bug.
You can create a toaster wrapper service, that opens the popup when you are only on the browser. For this we use isPlatformBrowser.
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { ActiveToast, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ToasterManagerService {
  isBrowser = false;
  constructor(
    private readonly _toasterService: ToastrService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }

  success(message: string) {
    if (!this.isBrowser) return;
    return this._toasterService.success(message);
  }

  clear(toastId: number) {
    if (!this.isBrowser) return;
    this._toasterService.clear(toastId);
  }
}

Then we can call the methods from this service on the component and it should start working.
import { afterNextRender, Component, inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ActiveToast, ToastrModule, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ToasterManagerService } from './toaster-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, ToastrModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-toaster';
  private readonly toasterManager = inject(ToasterManagerService);
  toastId!: number;
  constructor() {
    const toast = this.toasterManager.success('Close already!') || null;
    if (toast) {
      this.toastId = toast.toastId;
    }
  }

  clear() {
    console.log(`Clear`);
    this.toasterManager.clear(this.toastId);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo -> cd test -> npm i -> npm run start
